# Retrieve paired Bluetooth devices from console

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Is there any way to retrieve all paired bluetooth devices ("Friendly name" and MAC-Adress) from the console? Is there any universal solution for any Linux distribution?

In case there isn't: I'm using an Ubuntu derivative.

I already tried some stuff with `hcitool`, but nothing worked so far...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Late to the party, I tried listing as suggested by @panmari and @MarkCh but I was getting some unknown mac addresses (on a C.H.I.P with Debian), so I used the following command:

```
 bt-device -l
```

It will return both friendly name and Mac of all paired devices.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution myself. In Linux, the friendly names with their according mac adresses are saved in the file:

```
/var/bluetooth/{MAC-of-local-Bluetooth-device}/names
```

It should be easy enough to read it out with a shell script or the programming language of your choice.

Comment: It's /var/lib/bluetooth/{MAC-of-local-Bluetooth-device}/names on raspberry pi, but near enough, thanks!

Comment: This directory does not exist on Ubuntu 17, nor the file `names`, but `/var/lib/bluetooth/<addr>/<addr>/info` exists

Answer (score 5):

Install `bluez-utils`, run `bluetoothctl paired-devices`. See `bluetoothctl --help` for more useful commands.

Comment: I am using Raspian on Raspberry Pi 4 and connected my Bluetooth keyboard via the GUI. After setting boot mode to CLI it did not work anymore. bluez-tools (now bluez) was already installed. After starting `bluetoothctl` I saw with the command `paired-devices`, that no keyboard was connected. With `scan on` I was able to find out the device address and pair it with `pair <address>`, trust it with `trust <address>` and connect it with `connect <address>`